# How to Get App Approved After Rejection From Play Console?

Tags: android, publish, google-play-console

**Hear Me Out Please!**
I have checked out all the related questions and nothing is helping so far.

**My Problem**
My app was not on the Play Store, I was distributing it directly and updating the app by downloading the new version using the app itself and then installing it. To install the app I had to request **REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES** permission.

**Now**
Now I wanted to publish it to play store. It's my first time publishing an app to Play Store. I uploaded the app and it got rejected reason was the above-mentioned permission. The EMail they send me is something like this:

```
    Issue details
    
    We found an issue in the following area(s):
    
    SPLIT_BUNDLE 20221007
Additionally, follow these steps to bring your app into compliance:

Please remove the use of REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission from your app.
```

Full Mail Image Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqrJB.jpg

**After This**
I have removed the permission and all its code from my app, created a new build and resubmitted, after a day it also got rejected quoting the same issue. I tried with 6 or 7 builds and they all got rejected.

I don't understand for some reason, the google review team is not reviewing the latest version I upload but the same first version 20221007. And then they send me the same email.

**My Question**
What Am I doing wrong? how do I submit the new version?
So that my app gets verified and published. Honestly Saying I Am Frustrated Right Now.

Comment: Have you increased your `versionCode` and `versionName`?

Comment: Yes, I did change them in every build I uploaded.

Comment: Run bundletool dump manifest command to see if the permission is actually removed from the app bundle you upload to the console. And try a clean build as well.

Comment: I think you got my question incorrect, I have removed the permission. The problem is Google's Review Teams is reviewing the same old version not the new ones I upload.